# How can I visualize the costs of the proxemics layer?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use the social navigation layer of the people stack. I have a node which gives me the relative positions of the people in front of the depth camera and I would like to incorporate this information into the navigation costmap. So far I can see the added social layer in the costmap when I run rqt_reconfigure but I was wondering if there is a way to visualize the costs of that layer in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201281/how-can-i-visualize-the-costs-of-the-proxemics-layer?/) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can visualize the costmap by adding a Map type display to rviz connected to the COSTMAP_NAMESPACE/costmap topic. This assumes that COSTMAP_NAMESPACE/publish_frequency is greater than 0.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2015-01-20**:
Thank you for your response. My social costmap was not properly configured. That was why I could not see it in the local or global costmap visualization.